# Mamp won't start apache windows 10

Tags: mamp

I have mamp installed but Apache won't start. I've read loads of posts and checked through the logs but there's no sign of what's wrong. There isn't even an Apache log in the mamp\logs folder. And the mampapp log doesn't show any errors.

Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction as the logs have left me nothing to go on!

Answer (score 0):

The port in mamp's apache settings is free? Sometimes another sorftware use the default port 8080 from mamp (or 80 if you change it), I remember having problems with skype opened before mamp